# issue with http put in Angular 4 - doesn't seem to execute

Tags: angular, http-put

So is this how you make a http put request in Angular 4?
I have a working get, the put should be similar:

```
approve(id: string): Observable<any> {
    const requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.httpClient.put(
        `${this.endpointUrl}/${id}`,
        null,
        { headers: requestHeaders, responseType: 'text' as 'text' })
        .map(rez => JSON.parse(rez))
        // .catch(error => this.handleError(error));
}
```

is the syntax correct for empty body?
no error is logged in the console, so no hints why it doesn't work. if i do it through swagger i get the expected changes in the database.
I actually hardcoded this `${this.endpointUrl}/${id}`, line to make sure the url is correct too (same as swagger).

Comment: should null be a string? or Json? If you want to pass nothing why use put?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http client requests are "cold" observables that don't execute right away in Angular that need to be subscribed to in order to make them "hot" (execute).

You need to call this like

```
approve(1).subscribe();
```